# Vscode extension, setting window.activeTextEditor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I use the vscode extension api to set the `activeTextEditor`?

The reason I need this is because my extension depends on an external call to extension B, and extension B does not take an argument for editor. It just looks at `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`.

My extension is a webview which calls Extension B when something is clicked on the webview. At that moment in time, the 'active tab' is the webview, which is not `activeTextEditor` that I want.

I want to do something like

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor = editor
```

at the start of my click handler, but this doesn't work because `activeTextEditor` is not a setter.

I tried making a fake edit on the editor in question:

```
function changeFocus(editor: vscode.TextEditor) {
  return editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
    const pos = new vscode.Position(0, 0);
    const nxt = new vscode.Position(0, 1);
    editBuilder.insert(pos, "\\");
    editBuilder.delete(new vscode.Range(pos, nxt));
  });
}
```

but this does not change `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` variable (it is still `undefined`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this opens and focuses another file:

```js
const currentWorkSpace = await vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);

vscode.window.showTextDocument(vscode.Uri.joinPath(currentWorkSpace.uri, 'search/oldSearch.js'), { preview: false });
```

It is focussed and writable at its previously saved cursor position.

`showTextDocument()` has two other forms, one of which can take a `TextDocument` as the file to be opened, rather than a `Uri`.

There is also `openTextDocument()` which can create a new untitled file if you wish.

If the file is already open, this code will still serve to focus it and thus you have your `activeTextEditor`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I just tried using
vscode.window.showTextDocument(editor.document.uri)
to change focus to the file that I want.
Unfortunately showTextDocument opens the file in the currently active tab, instead of changing focus to the editor that already has the file open.

I added some more details about my use case to the OP.

Comment: Ok, I got it working:


vscode.window.showTextDocument(editor.document.uri, {
    preview: false,
    viewColumn: editor.viewColumn,
  });

Thanks!

Comment: @AnttiS. Been using your technique for a few days.  It's great.  Tricky to find / re find this kind of thing in the docs!